# Can we use templates to send emails with SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Using the Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_createHTMLEmailandSend.htm) I can see we can build HTML emails and use SSJS to send to lists.

I wanted to know if its possible to use a predefined Email (in Content Builder) and use that for the send instead?

Here is the code to send using an on-the-fly email:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

    // Include SSJS Core Library
    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    // retrieve all the lists in the account
    var retrievedLists = List.Retrieve();

    // set up and add an email                                
    var emailData = {
        "CustomerKey" : "Cool_Email_Key",
        "Name" : "Cool Email",
        "HTMLBody" : "<body bgcolor='#ffffff' text='#000000'><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='1' bordercolor='#000000' bgcolor='#ffffff' width='600' align='center'><tr><td align='center'><font face='verdana' size='1' color='#444444'>To view this email as a web page, click <a href='%%view_email_url%%'>here.</a></font></span><br/><br/><center><h2>Way Cool Email</h2></center><br/><br/><table cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' width='600' ID='tblRequired' Border=0><tr><td><font face='verdana' size='1' color='#444444'>This email was sent to: %%emailaddr%% <br><br><b>Email Sent By:</b> %%Member_Busname%%<br>%%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%<br><br></td></tr></table><a href='%%profile_center_url%%' alias='Update Profile'>Update Profile</a><custom name='opencounter' type='tracking'></td></tr></table>",
        "Subject" : "Check out my way cool email",
        "IsHTMLPaste" : "true"
    };

    // Create the email
    newEmail = Email.Add(emailData);
    // Send the email to all the lists
    status = Send.Add("Cool_Email_Key", retrievedLists);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You simply need to replace the "Cool_Email_Key" from your created email with an existing emails customer key. See [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_sendAdd.htm). You can also change the From name, etc to a customized value.

Example of options:

```
var options = {
    FromName : "JSON Specified Name",
    FromAddress : "aruiz@example.com",
    Subject : "JSON Test Mail"
};
```

Below is a full example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

    // Include SSJS Core Library
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

    // retrieve all the lists in the account
    var retrievedLists = List.Retrieve();

    // Options
    var options = {
        FromName : "JSON Specified Name",
        FromAddress : "aruiz@example.com",
        Subject : "JSON Test Mail"
    };

    // Send the email to all the lists
    status = Send.Add("Existing_Email_CustKey", retrievedLists, options);
</script>
```